# Build script is unable to find crate that is listed in the [dependencies] section

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Minimal reproducible example:

**build.rs**

```rust
extern crate pkg_config;

fn main() {}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
pkg-config = "0.3"
```

Running `cargo check` or `cargo build` on this example results in an error: `error[E0463]: can't find crate for pkg_config`.

Cargo downloaded the crate just fine and I've verified that I have pkg-config installed. Is there some rule I'm missing about `build.rs` dependencies? Is there some other configuration I need specifically for pkg-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pkg-config under `[dependencies]`, you need to list it under `[build-dependencies]` in your Cargo.toml file. Cargo differentiates between the two. The first is for the app or library, while the `[build-dependencies]` are for the build.rs script.